# When I add Actuator dependency it gives UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a springboot application. When I add spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency to my pom it gives UnsatisfiedDependencyException. 
Without this dependency, application is running. When I put it, application not running.

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

**Error:**

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'servoMetricCollector' defined in class path resource

Comment: What are all the bean you are autowiring in servoMetricCollector.?

Comment: can you provide more information like code for servoMetricCollector or what are all the config you have done for actuator

Comment: I added only the **info** endpoint to the application.yml